# How to config rancher to send multiline logs to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, multiline, rancher

I'm trying to send micro-services logs to elasticsearch,it worked,but all the logs that send to ES are single line including exception stacktrace.
I am using Rancher, How sholud i configue in Rancher to send muliti-line logs to ES.

Comment: Here's my rancher.(sorry,my reputation is not enough to post a picture)
(pic-[link](https://github.com/chen-jie/wzry/raw/master/rancher.png))

Here's my kibana.(pic-[link](https://github.com/chen-jie/wzry/raw/master/kibana.png))As you can see the stack trace logs are not in the single line.